# does the block's nonce in Ethash dependes on previous nonce?

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, ethash

does the algorithm of Ethash use previous nonce to calculate the nonce for the current block? If it doesn't depends, then I could implement the algorithm to run it in parallel, and then , I could find many nonces and reuse them for future blocks. Is this correct?

Basically , my question is, if nonces for the blocks can be accumulated for future reuse, or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't reuse nonces.

The Ethash algorithm applies to the block header serialized (without the nonce). The block headers includes this fields that depends on previous blocks or like timestamp and block number that is always increasing:

- Parent block hash
- Current block number
- Timestamp